# Do buck converters/voltage regulators change max amperage?

Tags: voltage-regulator, buck, amperage

I'm interested in dc-dc buck converters and voltage regulators. I want to know if the maximum amperage changes when you adjust voltage or if amperage is affected at all when changing voltage.

Thanks

Comment: No, it's pretty much fixed by the inductor. At extremely low duty cycle, other effects will come into play too but over the usable input voltage range and output voltage (if adjusable), it has the same output current capability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several different things that can limit the maximum output current of a buck converter, and of course the lowest sets the overall limit. Different configurations or ambient temperatures may change which limit wins, so it's not always easy to translate specifications for one configuration into another.

The output power can't be greater than the input power, and in fact 90% or so of the input power, depending on the efficiency. If the input power is limited, it will limit your output.

The inductor has two limits on its maximum current, thermal from \$I^2 R\$ losses (which will depend on ambient temperature), and magnetic saturation.

The input switch will have a limit on maximum current. It will have a thermal rating, and it may have a programmed upper limit set by the controller for protection.

Answer (score 2):

For a perfect buck operated in continuous conduction mode or CCM (the inductor current never returns to 0 within a switching cycle), the output voltage is defined as \$V_{out}=DV_{in}\$. As you can see, the current you can obtain is independent from the inductance value \$L\$. However, the perfect relationship I gave can be updated when considering the inductor ohmic loss \$r_L\$, the dc resistance of the inductor, which affects the output voltage in this way: \$V_{out}=\frac{R_L}{r_L+R_L}DV_{in}\$ where \$R_L\$ is the load resistance. You can improve this formula by adding the MOSFET \$r_{DS(on)}\$ contribution as well as the diode forward drop \$V_f\$. What I want to say is that \$L\$ in theory does not affect \$V_{out}\$ but you can see that a larger inductance (more turns) will lead to a larger \$r_L\$ and a reduction of \$V_{out}\$ in open-loop operations. In closed-loop operations, \$D\$ will naturally increase to compensate these losses.

Actually, you can see the buck as a low-impedance square-wave generator followed by a low-pass \$LC\$ filter tuned at \$\omega_0\$. If the inductance is small, you increase the ripple current (and the ripple voltage) because the cutoff frequency is high. The peak and valley inductor currents increase but not the average current. On the other hand, if you increase \$L\$, you filter more and reduce the output voltage and inductor ripple but you increase ohmic losses. The below picture shows the inductor ripple current for 3 different inductance values in an open-loop-operated buck converter: the ripple changes but the average value remains constant (\$r_L\$ is constant here). Please note that we are still in CCM.

[image]

Now, if your buck is driven by a controller featuring a maximum peak current limit, then you need to look closer at the operating waveforms. The maximum output current you'll get is the inductor peak current minus half of the ripple: \$I_{out}=I_{L,peak}-\frac{\Delta I_L}{2}\$ in which the inductor ripple current \$\Delta I_L\$ is defined by the difference between the inductor peak  and valley values: \$\Delta I_L=I_{L,peak}-I_{L,valley}\$ (see the below picture). The valley value is reached at the end of \$t_{off}\$ and is defined by \$I_{L,valley}=I_{L,peak}-t_{off}S_{off}\$ in which the off-slope is defined by \$S_{off}\approx\frac{V_{out}}{L}\$. So you see that with a given controller defining a maximum peak current \$I_{peak,max}\$ you won't be able to deliver a continuous output current greater than this peak value minus \$\frac{\Delta I_L}{2}\$. The "best" case is with a very large inductance leading to a very small ripple and giving \$I_{out}\approx I_{peak,max}\$. However, you never design a buck converter with such a  low inductor ripple current for many reasons and one of them being reaction speed: as an inductance opposes current changes, if your buck features a large inductance value, any output current demands will be answered slowly, the time the current in the inductor builds up cycle by cycle. The up-slope in this time is \$S_{on}\approx\frac{V_{in}-V_{out}}{L}\$ and it will be small if \$L\$ is large. The second argument is of course efficiency: as pointed out, a large inductance will imply a bulky inductor with a lot of turns and, consequently, a large \$r_L\$ component leading to extra losses. As such, designers usually adopt 30-40% of ripple current in \$L\$ as a first starting point. There is plenty to say on the buck and one good source could be this [book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0071823468).

[image]

Comment: I love the detail but I just wanted the conciseness.